# Intersection of spans

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the intersection $U\cap W$ where $U=\operatorname{span}(4x-e^{3x},2+e^{3x})$ and $W=\operatorname{span}(1,e^x,e^{3x})$.

Can someone give a hint?

---

My textbook's answer is simply $U\cap W=\operatorname{span}(2+e^{3x})$..

Comment: You can consider them as subspaces of $\operatorname{span}(1,x,e^x,e^{3x})$ (exercise: these four functions are linearly independent) and look at the coordinates in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Notice that $U$ is a 2-dimensional vector space. Clearly $2 + e^{3x}$ is in $U \cap W$, so $U\cap W$ must either be one dimensional with this generator or it must be all of $U$. Is $4x$ in $W$?